# Magento 2.1.7 theme installation

Tags: theme

I purchased a theme off of TemplateMonster the install instructions are pretty straight forward - move app folder into your store root directory and enable the theme.  So I did that and the theme showed fine in the design configuration settings the issue I'm having is I'm unable to see the "TemplateMonster"  heading under store configuration that has options for things like the megamenu and other plugins that come with the theme.  The documentation doesn't really have any kind of FAQ/Troubleshooting I've logged a ticket with the developer however just wanted to see if anyone else has a quick fix for this.

After moving the theme files to root directory 2 new themes show in my design config - "TemplateMonster Theme"  and "TemplateMonster Framework"  my guess is that the framework stores all the plugins etc. however not sure where to go from here.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: did u completed the commands, deploy ,compile and upgrade, cache and permissions properly

Comment: Go to content->configuration-> select the installed theme

Comment: deploy compile and upgrade?  i have setup cron jobs correctly so the site re-indexes every minute. cache has been cleared.  what about permissions?

Comment: Give permissions: 777 for var, pub, and app

Comment: or you can give 777 for hole magento

Comment: it was the upgrade and compile commands that i had missed they werent mentioned in the documentation for the theme.  Shivashankar m if you want to add as an answer i will mark as correct

Comment: Go for stores configuration, is there any import demos options available?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: I did i just needed to run upgrade and recompile in the magento root and that fixed all my theme issues.

Comment: @maxfuller I am tried to apply magento 2.0.0 theme to magento 2.1.7, is possible?

Comment: It might but it might not id give it a go on a dev site or staging site but dont try on production